# 'expo' not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: npm, expo, npx

I installed expo-cli using npm but after the successful installation, when i try to run expo --version, it shows that expo in nor recognized. I tried adding path to the environment variables but that doesn't seem to work. I have to start working on React Native. Are there any go throughs to this issue?

Comment: Use npm i -g expo-cli to install it globally.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one solution to get

```
'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

## Solution 1

Make sure you have installed it global
For npm

```
npm  install -g expo-cli
```

For Yarn

```
yarn add -g expo-cli
```

## Solution 2

Make Sure you have added

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

to your environmental Variable. I already faced this issue and solved by adding above to my environmental Variable

## Solution 3

I don't know how to category this solution, Try to run

```
npm cache clear -f
```

in your terminal and

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Comment: Instead of saying _Reason_, maybe say _Solution_.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried all of these methods. it installs successfully but doesn't show up in the npm folder like other packages